# How exactly does initialization list make code run faster in C++?

Tags: c++, class, assembly, g++

I have a simple class

```
class ImaginaryNumber {
    private:
    int _real;
    int _imaginary;
    public:
    ImaginaryNumber(int real, int imaginary) {
        _real = real;
        _imaginary = imaginary;
    }
};

int main() {
    ImaginaryNumber i = ImaginaryNumber(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembler code is the exact same thing when I change the constructor to an initialization list (compiled with `g++ -S main.cpp`). So in what case does it make a difference?

Comment: You'll need to use default constructible member types to see a performance difference

Comment: Change to `int const _real; int const _imaginary;`.

Comment: Because all members will be initialized anyway before you get to the body of your constructor. So adding code there doubles the workload